# Highcharts stuck on panning

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, highcharts

I'm trying to open highcharts on new browser windows so i'm doing something like this.

```
let chartWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "left=0,top=0,width=600,height=450");
let chartContainer = $("<div />", {
            class: "chart-container"
        });
$(chartWindow.document.body).append(chartContainer);
Highcharts.chart(chartContainer[0], chartOptions);
```

But if more than one window is open and if you try to zoom on other windows apart from the first one the click get stuck. Seems like some event is not firing properly. So if you try to select the chart to zoom it gets stuck and you have to go to the first chart that was opened and click there to fix it. I'm sure is because of opening the charts on new windows but i need to do it.

What could be the problem here?

Edit: code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem looks like a bug, so I reported it on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9748

As a workaround you can edit Highcharts Pointer methods `setDOMEvents`:

```
    if (!H.unbindDocumentMouseUp) {
        H.unbindDocumentMouseUp = [];
    }
    H.unbindDocumentMouseUp.push(addEvent(
        ownerDoc,
        'mouseup',
        pointer.onDocumentMouseUp
    ));
```

and `destroy`:

```
            H.unbindDocumentMouseUp.forEach(function(unbind) {
                unbind();
            });
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cxz7hugp/

Comment: Not knowing Highcharts that well i came with my own rudimental solution to this problem where i register mouseup event on the window and did `chart.pointer.drop()`. But this is a much better solution. Thank you.